# Why do I get an Error about 'smart cast', when using a Delegate in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I created a Delegate class in Kotlin, for 'cyclic' variables, such as hours:

when '25' is added to an hour with initial value '0', the result should be '1',
since there is no such thing as '25' hours.

The class I created works, but when I reassign such a delegated variable,
and then print it using 'print(...)',
I get an Error saying 'Smart cast is impossible, X is a mutable variable'

Am I doing something wrong ?
How could I fix the problem ?

I have tried to add an explicit cast, which helped,
but gives a Warning saying 'No cast needed', while it does not work without the cast.

this is the minimal code to reproduce the Error:

```
    package <package name>

    import kotlin.reflect.KProperty


    fun main(){

        val test = Test()

        test.hour = 25

        print(test.hour)    

        // this works:      print(test.hour as Number)   ("No cast needed")

    }

    // just a class which uses the delegate
    class Test {
        var hour by CyclicVariable(24)
    }

    // the delegate class
    class CyclicVariable(val max: Number, var value: Number = 0){

        operator fun getValue(reference: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Number = value.toDouble()

        operator fun setValue(reference: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Number) {
            val result = value.toDouble() % max.toDouble()
            this.value = if (result >= 0) result else max.toDouble() + result
        }

    }
```

expected result: `1.0` on console

actual result:
`Error:(12, 11) Kotlin: Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'test.hour' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time`

Comment: This sample doesn't work for me even without print, it fails to build because `setValue` has `Number` + `Double` operation which is unresolved. You'll need to create discrete implementation for each number type to have it work properly.

Comment: After the comment of @Pawel I tested my code again, since I it worked for me when I tested it. It seems I forgot that I created an extension function for Number in the same package, for adding two 'Numbers'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs, because there is no method `print` with `Number` parameter.
You can just use `test.hour.toString()`.

Kotlin tries to cast this variable to `Int`, as it sees, that you set an int to the variable: `test.hour = 25`. But it can't, because the variable is mutable.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, which worked (use `toString()`). While experimenting a little further, I also think I know why the "unnecessary cast" worked: because it then seems to use the method `print(message: Any?)`, instead of the more specific method `print(message: Int)` which prevents the smart-cast I believe.